# Writing a number in an array that has the same number of counts like the number

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am working on a paging function. This is what I have:

```
$total_pages = 3; // 3 is only an example

foreach ($total_pages as $single_page):
echo 'Page'.$single_site->number.'|';
endforeach;
```

How can I write the number of pages in array that I can use in my foreach function?

The number of pages is dynamical. I want to be able, to show a value for each page like:
Page1, Page2 and so on. Dependening on the number of total pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
foreach (range(0, $total_pages - 1) as $single_page)
```

but even easier is to just use a normal `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $total_pages; $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html) is a great way to paginate data, and makes it relatively easy to implement a scrolling pagination control (showing only a subset of pages numbers relative to the current page number).  If your application has a lot of pages of results, then showing a scrolling pagination control will provide a better user experience than showing hundreds of "Page X" links in succession.

A sliding control might look like:  [Prev] 1 ... 4 5 6 7 8 ... 200 [Next]